# Partitions got corrupted for no reason

Tags: linux, hard-drive, partitioning

I have this MBR partition layout on two disks, internal and external:

```
-sda1 /boot
-sda2 /
-sda3 swap
-sda4 extended
    sda5 encrypted
    sda6 encrypted
```

The external disk is the same except it is obviously 'sdb.'

I needed to restore something from backup, but couldn't do it with the system running, so I booted from a bootable usb stick. I connected the external hard disk and copied what I wanted from two partitions: sdb2 and sdb5. I used pcmanfm to mount and umount the two partitions. Everything worked as expected.

I rebooted from the internal disk and then I remembered I wanted to copy something else. The additional file didn't require the system to go offline so I didn't use the usb stick. I connected the external disk again and... sdb5 and sdb6 popped up in pcmanfm as usual, but sdb1 and sdb2 didn't.

I tried to mount sdb2 manually on command line and mount didntt recognize it, claiming that I must specify the file system type. I did it as 'mount -t ext4' and it still won't work.

I thought maybe something else was broken on my system so I booted from the usb stick again and confirmed the problem. I booted into the regular system (internal disk) again, and the problem persists.

I tried opening sdb5 and it decrypts, but won't mount for the same reason: unindentified file system. sdb6 still opens.

The two disks look exactly the same on 'fdisk -l' but not on 'lsblk -f'. All partitions except sdb6 have no file system identification on the external disk.

```
# lsblk -f
NAME                FSTYPE      LABEL UUID   MOUNTPOINT
sda                                        
├─sda1              ext2        boot  [uuid] 
├─sda2              ext4        root  [uuid] /
├─sda3                                                
│ └─swap            swap              [uuid] [SWAP]
├─sda4                                                 
├─sda5              crypto_LUKS       [uuid] 
│ └─cxx             xfs         cr1   [uuid] /crypt1
└─sda6              crypto_LUKS       [uuid] 
  └─czz             xfs         cr2   [uuid] /crypt2
sdb                                                    
├─sdb1                                                 
├─sdb2                                                 
├─sdb3                                                 
├─sdb4                                                 
├─sdb5              crypto_LUKS       [uuid] 
│ └─luks-[uuid]                                          
└─sdb6              crypto_LUKS       [uuid] 
  └─luks-[uuid]     xfs         cr2b  [uuid] /media/root/cr2b
```

I can't see or understand how that happened. I have other copy of the data, but now I am very suspicious of the external disk. Can I still trust it? Is there any way I can fix that partition table so I don't have to copy everything again? I thought about opening it and re-saving it on cfdisk or fdisk, but since one of the encrypted partitions also has lost its FS label, I am not quite sure of how to do it.

Comment: Did you copy from the external disk, directly over the partitions, instead of mounting them first?

Comment: Was one disk binary cloned to the other at some moment in the past, so their partitions shared UUIDs? I cannot tell if it could cause your exact problem, but such a situation has unexpectedly bitten me once and taught to be careful with it.

Comment: I just copied a couple of directories with rsync. Nothing else.

Answer (score 0):

A difference between `fdisk` and `lsblk` is that `fdisk` reads from the disk, while `lsblk` list the kernel's view of the devices from `sysfs`. Not that this solves your problem, but it's a good thing to keep in mind while trying to figure out partition problems. Running `dmesg | grep sd` you should get an idea of whatever the kernel detected while booting, like disks, partitions, etc. If `sda` and `sdb` are identical, you should have similar entries.

Comment: However, note that I said: "I thought maybe something else was broken on my system so I booted from the usb stick again and confirmed the problem. I booted into the regular system (internal disk) again, and the problem persists."

So I get the problem in two different systems. The usb stick is quite old, about three, maybe four years.

Comment: Did you try `smartctl -a /dev/sdb`? Does it report any errors like unreadable or pending sectors, etc?

Comment: I hadn't thought about that. I tried and got this output:

`# smartctl -a /dev/sdb
Read Device Identity failed: Unknown error

A mandatory SMART command failed: exiting. To continue, add one or more '-T permissive' options.`

I thought it could be a problem with the USB case, so I used another, and the original problem persisted, but then smartctl gave me output. Too big for this space, please read it here:

http://pastebin.com/zysdsLpQ

Looks OK to me, but I could be wrong.

Even with the other case, I still can't access those partitions.